# Calculate won, tie and lost games in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.5

I have two tables "matches" and "opponents".

Matches

```
id | date
---+------------
1  | 2016-03-21 21:00:00
2  | 2016-03-22 09:00:00
...
```

Opponents
(score is null if not played)

```
id | match_id | team_id | score
---+----------+---------+------------
1  |  1       |  1      |  0
2  |  1       |  2      |  1
3  |  2       |  3      |  1
4  |  2       |  4      |  1
4  |  3       |  1      |  
4  |  3       |  2      |  
....
```

The goal is to create the following table

```
Team | won | tie | lost | total
-----+-----+-----+------+----------
2    | 1   | 0   | 0    | 1
3    | 0   | 1   | 0    | 1
4    | 0   | 1   | 0    | 1
1    | 0   | 0   | 1    | 1
```

Postgres v9.5

How do I do this? (Im open to maybe moving the "score" to somewhere else in my model if it makes sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide et impera my son

```
with teams as (
    select distinct team_id from opponents
), 
teamgames as (
    select t.team_id, o.match_id, o.score as team_score, oo.score as opponent_score 
    from teams t
    join opponents o on t.team_id = o.team_id
    join opponents oo on (oo.match_id = o.match_id and oo.id != o.id)
),
rankgames as (
    select 
        team_id, 
        case 
            when team_score > opponent_score then 1
            else 0
        end as win,
        case 
            when team_score = opponent_score then 1
            else 0
        end as tie,
        case 
            when team_score < opponent_score then 1
            else 0
        end as loss
    from teamgames
),
rank as (
    select 
        team_id, sum(win) as win, sum(tie) as tie, sum(loss) as loss,
        sum( win * 3 + tie * 1 ) as score
    from rankgames
    group by team_id
    order by score desc
)
select * from rank;
```

**Note1**: You probably don't need the first "with" as you probably have already a table with one record per team

**Note2**: i think you can also achieve the same result with one single query, but in this way steps are clearer

Comment: Thansk @Jack, that does the trick. I was thinking in a total different direction with LATERAL joins etc.